# IComparable: Cannot implement an interface member because it is not public

Tags: c#, compareto

I'm already aware that there are many other similar questions regarding this topic, however looking at the answers and adapting my code in relation to those has proved unsuccessful.

The code below is part of my Artist class, where I use CompareTo to compare between the artist name and the artist name (obj) passed in..

```
class Artists : IComparable
{
    private string artistName;
    private string artistMembers;

    public int CompareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Artists otherArtist = (Artists)obj;
        return artistName.CompareTo(otherArtist.ArtistName);
    }


    public Artists(string artist, string members){
        ArtistName = artist;
        Members = members;
    }

    public string ArtistName
    {
        set { artistName = value; }
        get { return artistName; }
    }
    public string Members
    {
        set { artistMembers = value; }
        get { return artistMembers; }
    }

}
```

I really want to avoid making the variables public, which is a solution offered elsewhere, so I was wondering what I need to do to sort this problem out, and what I am doing wrong so I can learn from mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2** 
Closed VS and recompiled, and suddenly worked. Sorry for time wasting.

Comment: I'm lost, what isn't working/you want to change in the above code?

Comment: Your code compiles - what _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: You should consider implementing `IComparable<Artists>` instead of the non-generic version.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming from your error that `CompareTo` is *not* `public` in your *real* code.  Implicit interface implementations must be public.

You *could* implement the interface *explicitly*, and then clients would have to cast to `IComparable` to see the method:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(Object obj)  // will be private unless explicitly using the interface
{
    Artists otherArtist = (Artists)obj;
    return artistName.CompareTo(otherArtist.ArtistName);
}

Artists a1 = new Artists("Beatles", "Paul, Ringo");
Artists a2 = new Artists("U2", "Bono");
// this will fail:
//int i = a1.CompareTo(a2);

// this will work:
int i = ((IComparable)a1).CompareTo(a2);
```

However note that your class is `internal` by default, so the *class* is not even public.